# Trying to Package Unity game in Ubuntu Linux debian

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unity-game-engine, packaging

I created a Unity game for Linux, and now I am trying to Package it in debian so that I can upload it afterwards to the Ubuntu Software Center. I have prepared everything and when I use this command `debuild -d -us -uc`, I get this error:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: using a gain-root-command while being root
dpkg-buildpackage: source package rainingcoins
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 109.0
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution precise
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by CrazySoft Limited <info@crazysoft.gr>
 dpkg-source --before-build rainingcoins-109.0
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture i386
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean 
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
   dh_clean
 dpkg-source -b rainingcoins-109.0
dpkg-source: info: using source format `3.0 (native)'
dpkg-source: info: building rainingcoins in rainingcoins_109.0.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: building rainingcoins in rainingcoins_109.0.dsc
 debian/rules build
dh build 
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_configure
   dh_auto_build
   dh_auto_test
 fakeroot debian/rules binary
dh binary 
   dh_testroot
   dh_prep
   dh_auto_install
   dh_install
   dh_installdocs
   dh_installchangelogs
   dh_pysupport
dh_pysupport: This program is deprecated, you should use dh_python2 instead. Migration guide: http://deb.li/dhs2p
   dh_icons
   dh_perl
   dh_link
   dh_compress
   dh_fixperms
   dh_strip
   dh_makeshlibs
   dh_shlibdeps
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library librt.so.1 needed by debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins_Data/Mono/x86_64/libmono.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64'; RPATH: '')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library libdl.so.2 needed by debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins_Data/Mono/x86_64/libmono.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64'; RPATH: '')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library libpthread.so.0 needed by debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins_Data/Mono/x86_64/libmono.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64'; RPATH: '')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library libm.so.6 needed by debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins_Data/Mono/x86_64/libmono.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64'; RPATH: '')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library libc.so.6 needed by debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins_Data/Mono/x86_64/libmono.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64'; RPATH: '')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins_Data/Mono/x86_64/libmono.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64'; RPATH: '')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 needed by debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins_Data/Plugins/x86_64/ScreenSelector.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64'; RPATH: '')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 needed by debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins_Data/Plugins/x86_64/ScreenSelector.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64'; RPATH: '')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library libgobject-2.0.so.0 needed by debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins_Data/Plugins/x86_64/ScreenSelector.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64'; RPATH: '')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library libglib-2.0.so.0 needed by debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins_Data/Plugins/x86_64/ScreenSelector.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64'; RPATH: '')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library libdl.so.2 needed by debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins_Data/Plugins/x86_64/ScreenSelector.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64'; RPATH: '')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library libgcc_s.so.1 needed by debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins_Data/Plugins/x86_64/ScreenSelector.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64'; RPATH: '')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library libc.so.6 needed by debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins_Data/Plugins/x86_64/ScreenSelector.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64'; RPATH: '')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins_Data/Plugins/x86_64/ScreenSelector.so (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64'; RPATH: '')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot continue due to the errors listed above
Note: libraries are not searched in other binary packages that do not have any shlibs or symbols file.
To help dpkg-shlibdeps find private libraries, you might need to use -l.
dh_shlibdeps: dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/rainingcoins.substvars debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins_Data/Plugins/x86/ScreenSelector.so debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins_Data/Plugins/x86_64/ScreenSelector.so debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins_Data/Mono/x86/libmono.so debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins_Data/Mono/x86_64/libmono.so debian/rainingcoins/opt/rainingcoins/raining_coins.x86 returned exit code 2
make: *** [binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1364:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc failed
```

My rules file is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# -*- makefile -*-
# Sample debian/rules that uses debhelper.
# This file was originally written by Joey Hess and Craig Small.
# As a special exception, when this file is copied by dh-make into a
# dh-make output file, you may use that output file without restriction.
# This special exception was added by Craig Small in version 0.37 of dh-make.

# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
#export DH_VERBOSE=1

%:
    dh $@
```

Any Ideas to help me?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are trying to build a package containing amd64 binaries on a i386 host system.

This is what confuse [dh_shlibdeps](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/dh_shlibdeps.1.html).

If this is not a mistake and you really want to mix architectures in a single package, I guess your best solution would be to completely skip this step.
You can do so by adding something like the following to your debian/rules:

```
override_dh_shlibdeps:
    @echo "Skipping dh_shlibdeps"
```

If you do that, you will have to manually fill your package dependencies in debian/control as they won't be autodetected.